# How to cut off the end by converting double to int?

Tags: c#, .net, math, double, int

I think you will loughing at me, but I need help here...

I have a double (4.5234234) and need this in Int, but everytime without the numbers after the points. So it doesn't mathers if its 4.01 or 4.99 it should ever be 4 in Int.

how to do that?

Comment: `int intValue = (int)doubleValue;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you actually tried this?

```
double myDouble = 4.5234234;
int result = (int)myDouble;
//at this point result is 4
```

This will "strip" everything after the decimal point, and only return the whole number part of the double.

Comment: if you do it this way you probably need to ensure that myDouble is in range for int first

Comment: @jk - That is true. You might get some unexpected results if not. One way is to check if `myDouble > int.MaxValue` or not.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Math.Truncate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2eabd70.aspx) method.

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Double
>
> The integral part of d; that is, the number that remains after any fractional digits have been discarded.

Answer (score 0):

a nasty but workable way is i guess to round it first using

```
          double d = 5.555;
          int a = (int)d;
```

Comment: Why Math.Floor before the cast? the cast to int will effectively "floor" the value for you anyway, so the Math.Floor call is redundant.

Comment: `-5.55` will return `-6`, not `-5` with this solution.

Comment: @FredrikMörk and this is true mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Convet method:

```
double d = 5.555;
int i = Convert.ToInt(d);
```

Mitja